# Deploying to Microsoft azure via dropbox

Tags: eclipse, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I just started using Azure and the instructions to deploy a web app seem pretty straightforward. So my application is a backend and it works fine on local so I know the problem is not from the application but from my deployment. The application is also written in java and hibernate. I used this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/new-deploy-to-windows-azure-web-sites-from-dropbox/) to deploy the application to azure but the url still shows [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls741.png)

on the dashboard, it does show that the application got the code base from dropbox [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTFWy.png)

and the folder name in dropbox and code base name in eclipse match so I just copied and pasted the contents from the workspace into the dropbox. I also restarted the application but nothing changed. What am I missing? I appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your Azure image it is from the bare app service URL i.e .azurewebsites.net which is showing that you selected Java 8+ as your runtime and Tomcat 8+ as your container. Are you using any context path to access your backend i.e https://HOST:PORT/CONTEXT_PATH. So try with .azurewebsites.net/CONTEXT_PATH. Also if you are using spring-boot you have to edit web.config to run your jar file (like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-web-app-on-azure )

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I took a look at the link and followed the instructions but deployed via dropbox instead of ftp like it suggested and now my backend is live! thanks again!